# How to make Settings.settings data persistent

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, settings

I have a Windows Forms application and I'm using the Settings.settings class to store user's configuration (email preferences, theme, etc) I didn't realize that after the user closes the app, the settings are gone!!

This app is about to be released to production, so I have to provide a solution ASAP.

Comment: Describe what you are doing in more detail, please. Usually the settings are meant to be persistent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do have to save them after you set them.  Have you tried:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: I am do calling Save() but still they are empty on the next run. :(

Answer (score 3):

Are you using them like this?

```
... changes ...
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```